# Has something changed on Facebooks Graph today?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Has Facebook made a change to their Graph access today. For the past few months I've been able to access customers posts via the Json feed.

EG:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/posts?fields=promotable_id,message&access_token={user-access-token}
```

But all I'm getting back now is:

"To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review."

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it claims, you should submit an application to Facebook and get you endpoint approved for access 'Page Public Content Access'.

Our team submitted that application about a month ago and it passed. So we could access Page Public Content now.